# React Native null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction')

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I know there are a lot of answers to this, but my group and I have tried many solutions and still cannot get this to work.  We are creating a React-Native mobile application (and using Viro Media).  When we load the app on our phones (android and ios), we all get this exact error.  We have tried the linking and unlinking solution, as well as the pod install solution, among others, and we are still getting this error.  I think it might have something to do with the configuration files for ios and android, but I cannot be sure what would have to change.  I will put those below:

Package.Json:

```
  "name": "ViroSample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "./node_modules/react-viro/bin/run_ngrok.sh",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-viro": "2.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ViroSample' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ViroSample

  target 'ViroSample-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  end

  target 'ViroSampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'ViroSample-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ViroSample-tvOS

  target 'ViroSample-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

and settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'ViroSample'
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-screens'
project(':react-native-screens').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-screens/android')
include ':react-native-safe-area-context'
project(':react-native-safe-area-context').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android')
include ':@react-native-community_masked-view'
project(':@react-native-community_masked-view').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view/android')

include ':app'
```

Is there something we are missing here?  Like I said, we tried the linking solution, reinstalling, pod installing, and none of that worked.  Thanks.